# How OneSignal generates unique persistent user ID?

Tags: android, uuid, onesignal

I'm using [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/) to deliver push notifications to users using my app. When app is installed and started, a new user (player) ID is generated and sent to OneSignal servers, then you can query the users using your app in a web dashboard.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
    }

}
```

When I clear data and re-run the app, the user ID is still the same. I mean, the user ID is only re-created when I uninstall the app and re-install it. How is it done? I mean, where OneSignal stores the user ID created the first time in order to not to re-create each time.

If you store something in shared preferences or in a database, once you clear the app data, they are cleared, too. So, using shared preferences or database it won't work. I'm sure it's a silly thing but I wonder how it is implemented.

Comment: Sounds like the generation is done by communicating with the server.

Comment: In that case, how does the server know who is the device? How is the device "autenticated" when it asks the server for his user ID?

Comment: From the documentation: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/users-and-devices you can read that: It will stay the same as long as the user has your app installed...If the user hasn't opted out of the Google Ad id (Android) the ID will stay the same after full re-installs.

Comment: Thanks for the reference @ValentinoS. But, how is it implemented? How/Where is the user ID stored to not to be deleted when user does "Clear Data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make OneSignal work you should give it google_project_number (from Firebase) and Google_server_API_Key which you also take from firebase. And the other work onesignal makes for you in it's SDK. So, it's because firebase token. They send you new token only when you re-init play services (mostly when you reinstall or update the app) and than One-Signal make it's own id from this token in some ways.

Comment: No, you wrong. To make OneSignal work you should give it google_project_number (from Firebase) and Google_server_API_Key which you also take from firebase. And the other work onesignal makes for you in it's SDK

Comment: Ok, I did it too fast. if you want you can edit a little your answer here so I can upvote it and remove the downvote.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the answer. If it was helpful you can upvote it

Comment: Thanks for answering. How is it detected when play services are re-initialized?

Comment: Play Services tell to firebase that they are re-inits and firebase push new token. And your OneSignal background service handle it and send it's own id to OneSignal server. And if you ask how the firebase know if PlayServices re-init or not - I think, it's because you registered it in Manifest. And all data which was register in manifest not clearing when you clear the app. Only if you delete or update this app.